# How can i add bezier curve to Path in konva?

Tags: konvajs, konva

Could you please guide me on how bezier curve can be added to Path. Thanks!

here is my demo - [link](https://codepen.io/sandy-pedn/pen/WNavPoz)`here is my codepen`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate svg path with bezier curve like this:

```js
function computeQuadraticBezierPathData(p1, p2, p3) {
  const pathData = `M${p1.x},${p1.y} Q${p2.x},${p2.y} ${p3.x},${p3.y}`;
  return pathData;
}
```

To the `Konva.Path` do this:

```js
function updateLine() {
  var newpoints = computeQuadraticBezierPathData(circle1.position(), anchor.position(), circle2.position());
  path.setData(newpoints);
}
```

https://codepen.io/lavrton/pen/BaqoKJm

Comment: Thank you so much sir for this clear and detailed answer.